# Spring Security can't see credentials passed by Angular

Tags: angular, spring-security, authorization

I try to use spring security basic authorization. When i make post request from angular, spring can't recognize 'username' and 'password' properties. When i make post request from postman it works. I dont know if problem lies in spring configuration or angular request.

I have tried many configuration of post request but nothing works.

This is my spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("a").password("a").roles("*");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().
                csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();
    }
```

My up-to-date angular post request:

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  handleLogin(user: UserDto) {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('a' + ':' + 'a'),
       'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
});
    this.httpClient
      .post("//localhost:8080/login" ,{}, {headers}).subscribe(x=> {console.log(x)});
  }
```

This the place where spring security check credentials and result is null

```
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (this.postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        } else {
            String username = this.obtainUsername(request); //null
            String password = this.obtainPassword(request); //null
```

When i make post request from postman authorization works i hope that someone can help me with geeting seme result with anglar request.

-----------EDIT----------
As suggested in comment i tried this and still same problem.

```
let options = { headers: headers };
this.httpClient
  .post("//localhost:8080/login", {}, options).subscribe(x => { console.log(x) });
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use HTTP basic or form login? I guess you don't want form login, hence you should remove form login configuration or at least call another URL (`/login` is for form login only, doesn't support HTTP basic).

Answer (score 0):

With HttpClient.post the second parameter should be the request body, then options.

Maybe add

```
let options = { headers: headers };
this.httpClient.post(url, null, options);
```

https://v4.angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post

Pre-4.3 version of angular had an old http api with a different set of parameters that might be confusing you.

Comment: Thanks for response, unfortunatelly doesnt work, please check my edit